# как упаковать иконку ткинтер в exe?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

всем привет, что делать если при упаковке кода ткинтер в exe через pyinstaller, то выдает ошибку со строчкой в коде
window.iconbitmap("z.ico"),а без него без ошибки упаковывается в exe, только уже без иконки.
я пробовал pyinstaller --icon=z.ico, но иконка все равно стандартная при открытом окне .

Comment: Лучше не дублировать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Если нужно внести уточнения в вопрос, нажмите "править" под ним. При этом отредактированный вопрос поднимается на главной странице.

Answer (score 0):

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --name "имя приложения" --add-data "путь к иконке;."  "путь к файлу"

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Постораюсь, я начинающий) Про править я знаяю, спасибо.